# Can I stop EFCore from altering my Entity's state when I delete?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following typical Parent/Child classes, with the addition that all of my domain entities descend from a class `EntityBase` which has a method to return the owning object.

```cs
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    public abstract EntityBase GetRoot();
}

public class Parent : EntityBase
{
  private readonly List<Child> _children = new();
  public IReadOnlyList<Child> Children => _children.AsReadonly();
  
  public void RemoveChild(Child child)
  {
    _children.Remove(child);
  }
  
  public override GetRoot() => this;
}

public class Child : EntityBase
{
  public Parent Parent { get; init; }
  public string Name { get; set; } = "";
  
  public override GetRoot() => Parent;
}
```

If have some code in my DbContext that iterates over all modified entities, calls `GetRoot()` on them, to ensure their root (i.e. Parent) `EntityEntry` state is set to `Modified` if it is `Unchanged` so that I have a central point to check for DB update conflicts.

This works fine for modifications, but when I call `parent.RemoveChild(parent.Children[0])` and my DbContext attempts to save changes, my code calls `GetRoot` on the deleted child and receives `null` instead of the parent object that was fetched from the Db.

It seems that merely executing `ChangeTracker.Entries` to get the list of modified entries will alter the state of my `Child.Parent` property.

Is there a way I can get hold of a list of `ChangeTracker.Entries` without this happening?

Here is the code I execute before `SaveChangesAsync` in my `ApplicationDbContext`.

```cs
private void EnsureModifiedEntitiesAggregateRootsAreUpdated(EntityEntry[] modifiedEntries)
{
    foreach (var entry in modifiedEntries)
    {
        if (entry.State != EntityState.Unchanged)
        {
            var entity = (EntityBase)entry.Entity;

            // THIS NEXT LINE ALWAYS RETURNS NULL!
            var aggregateRoot = entity.GetAggregateRoot();

            EntityEntry<EntityBase> aggregateRootEntry = Entry(aggregateRoot);

            if (aggregateRootEntry.State == EntityState.Unchanged)
            {
                aggregateRootEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My app code does this

1. Fetch the Parent and use `.Include` to retrieve children
2. `parent.Items.RemoveAt(0);`
3. SaveChangesAsync

Comment: Shouldn't `_child.AsReadonly()` be `_children.AsReadonly()` ?

Comment: You could first mark the to-be-deleted child as modified and then as deleted. But isn't this far too expensive? I mean, if a child is only modified then isn't it enough to only check that single record for concurrent modifications? I can imagine that you want to check the entire tree if nodes are added/deleted.

Comment: @GertArnold The root of the multi-table aggregate is used as a central conflict locking point. So adding a child to the parent will also save the parent to ensure that no two people can alter the aggregate at the same time. For example, save the PurchaseOrder when adding a PurchaseOrderLine.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But I don't think it's necessary to modify the root when the tree *structure* doesn't change. Then I think it's enough to do standard concurrency checks for individual records.

Comment: One factor might be how you are deleting a child. Are you doing it from it's parent, or merely fetching the child from the DbContext and removing it from a DbSet? If the latter you might try `.Include(x => x.Parent)` when loading the child to remove it.

Comment: @GertArnold The root is used as a whole-structure locking point. Having locking on just a child/grandchild is not sufficient.

Comment: @StevePy I've updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to ensure that `GetRoot(entity)` was called whenever the ChangeTracker first detects an object is changing, and then the result in stored in a Dictionary.

I then use this to see what the original root values were.

Comment: EF neither has nor needs "repositories", it's a higher level Unit-of-Work. It doesn't have an `GetAggregateRoot` method either. This answer refers to missing custom code and can't help anyone else